# Can't use http_get() in a supabase trigger function

Tags: plpgsql, supabase, supabase-database

So I'm kind of new to databases in general, or at least not very experienced.
But in general I think I kind of understand how it all works.

So I had a trigger function to add row to a profile table when a new user signs up, it was all working as expected when I only was adding the user ID and the username, but then I decided to add an svg to the avatar and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my function:

```
declare
  svg text;
begin
  select content
  into svg
  from http_get(concat('https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/bottts/', new.id::text, '.svg'));
  
  insert into public.profile (id, username, avatar)
    values (
      new.id,
      new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'name',
      svg
    );

  return new;
end;
```

I've done a lot of trial and error and if I remove the http_get and just insert a string into avatar like so and it works:

```
declare
  svg text;
begin
  svg := 'this works...';
  insert into public.profile (id, username, avatar)
    values (
      new.id,
      new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'name',
      svg
    );

  return new;
end;
```

and I've also tried to export the http_call into an external function:

```
declare
  svg text;
begin
  select content
  into svg
  from http_get(concat('https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/bottts/', seed, '.svg'));
  
  return svg
end;
```

And call it, and it does return the svg html code as text as I would expect it to.

But then I add that function to the previous thing and it doesn't work:

```
  insert into public.profile (id, username, avatar)
    values (
      new.id,
      new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'name',
      get_dicebears_svg(new.id::text);
    );

  return new;
end;
```

I've also tried using `cast(new.id as text)` instead of `new.id::text`.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
SET search_path = extensions, public, pg_temp;
```